# Sitemap to display hash tag links or not?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap, hash

I am just creating sitemap for my site and wanted to find out if I should include # links for SEO?

**For Example:**

```
www.mydomain.com/#comment1

www.mydomain.com/#comment2
```

Does this help with SEO or because the page is essentially the same just conflict?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you shouldn't include # links. They refer to the same page, and the sitemap is saying how often the page changes (as well as page structure).

In fact, your server won't get a request for the #. The browser, or crawler bot, requests the URL www.mydomain.com and then when it retrieves the page jumps to the part of the page with the id of comment1, say.

(With [Ajax crawling](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/faq.html) it's a different matter, but you're probably not using that.)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the advice I was pretty sure that it wasn't worth including them but just wated to make doubly sure. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your sitemap file is intended to list the individual *documents/pages* on your site, not anchors.
Doing this makes no real sense. If you did this, what would stop you from also including every other conceivable anchor link, eg. index.php#nav, index.php#sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

These answers pretty much cover it all but if you want a good list of best practice tips for both HTML and XML sitemaps for SEO have a look at this:

http://www.marketing-jive.com/2010/04/14-sitemap-best-practices-for.html