# How to create google video sitemap urls for very large video files with distinct segments?

Tags: video, seo, sitemap, google-search-console

I have a large video files about 1 hr in duration, with different sections of the video corresponding to different distinct sub topics . For example, the whole video may be about an yoga exercise routine , with  10 minutes segment  for different yoga positions.

I want to have the video meta tags `"<video:tag>"`for each of the yoga position for the video file.

The problem is that if someone searching for 'YogaPosition_5'  clicks on the link, I do not think they will sit through the videos for  'YogaPosition_0' through 'YogaPosition_4' to get to 'YogaPosition_5'.

So is it possible to create **multiple "`<video:video>`" elements for the same video file**  with one `<video:tag>`  for each Yoga position long as long as I specify correct time offeset in the `<video:player_loc>` element like so

```
<video:player_loc allow_embed="yes" autoplay="ap=1">
         http://www.example.com/videoplayer.swf?video=123&timeOffset=50</video:player_loc>
```

for each corresponding `<video:tag>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Sitemaps are intended to list the individual pages of your blog, not every way something might view those pages, eg. [via anchors](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22411/sitemap-to-display-hash-tag-links-or-not). The video extension tags follow the same pattern: they're for listing what (whole) videos are on a given page. If the separate videos were accessible in some way, and then aggregated into your viewer with a playlist function, *then* it'd be appropriate to list them separately. But as you're describing right now, the multiple URLs would likely get ignored.